# ERROR actor.OneForOneStrategy error in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

The following error occurred in my Spark Streaming Kafka receiver program:

```
 ERROR actor.OneForOneStrategy: org.jnetpcap.protocol.network.Ip4java.io.NotSerializableException
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If checkpointing is enabled in Spark Streaming, then objects used in a function called in forEachRDD should be Serializable. Otherwise, there will be an "ERROR OneForOneStrategy. The code will run if we turn off checkpointing.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, this error indicates that some function in your job has referenced a non-serializable object (namely `org.jnetpcap.protocol.network.Ip4`).  Check out the ["ERROR OneForOneStrategy" article in the Databricks Spark Knowledgebase](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/spark_streaming/error_oneforonestrategy.html) for an example of how this problem can occur and a discussion of various workarounds / fixes.